# Get profile picture of specific phone number from contacts information

Tags: android

I am developing message send/receive application, and i need to get profile picture of phone number. Could any one please help me to get the profile picture of specific number?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber,Context context)
{
    contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
    int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
    Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(contactNumber)),new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
        contactLookupCursor.close();

    return phoneContactID;
}
```

The above method returns contactId of specific phone number and refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) to get profile picture from contactID.