# Android: how to get own profile picture like in native Messaging app

Tags: android, sms, messaging, user-profile

I'm writing an application for SMS messaging and I want to show profile picture of all senders (it is not a problem) and picture of my profile for sent messages. The same implementation was done in native Messaging app.
Could you please advice how I can get own profile picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html
and then
look into [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html)'s and [cursors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), write one to query for the photo uri or photo thumbnail uri.

Update

I found similar questions that should help you

[Get profile picture of specific phone number from contacts information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501446/get-profile-picture-of-specific-phone-number-from-contacts-information)

[Get user/owner profile contact URI and user image with API 8 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163088/get-user-owner-profile-contact-uri-and-user-image-with-api-8-onwards)

Comment: Thanks for information, I've used `ContactsContract.Profile` API

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for my question:

```
public static Bitmap getProfilePhoto(Context context) {
        Bitmap profilePhoto = null;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI);
        if (input != null) {
            profilePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } else {
            profilePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        }

        return profilePhoto;
    }
```

Comment: Works, i recomen use "true" in openContactPhoto for high res ;) InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,true);